# Looping through a for int loop from the inside, outwards

Tags: java, spiral

So I been making a program which takes a screenshot and then analyzes it. The problem is that it goes from top left to bottom right while checking, and I don't have a clue on how to implement checking outwards from the middle of the picture. Here is how far I have gotten :

```
breakthis : {
    for (int xpos = 250; xpos < 500; xpos++) {
        for (int ypos = 250; ypos < 500; ypos++) { //Starts at the middle (250), and supposed to go outwards for example : 251, 249, 252 etc..
            int color = image.getRGB(xpos, ypos);
            int red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int blue = color & 0x000000ff;
            if (red == 255) {
                System.out.println("Red has been found inside the picture");
                break breakthis;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : I have also thought about putting every number until 500 into an arraylist and then somehow sorting them based on their distance to 250 and using that instead, but I wasn't able to do that aswell

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not fastest or best designed method but it will accept consumer where you can operate on Point object looping spirally from the middle of the image until hitting last corner. Image does not have to be square.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpiralLoop.loop((Point p) -> System.out.println(p.x + "," + p.y), 500, 200);
    }
}

class SpiralLoop{
    public static void loop(Consumer<Point> consumer, int maxX, int maxY ) {
        int middleX = maxX/2;
        int middleY = maxY/2;
        Set<Point> edgesLeft = new HashSet<>();
        edgesLeft.add(new Point(0,0));
        edgesLeft.add(new Point(0,maxY));
        edgesLeft.add(new Point(maxX,0));
        edgesLeft.add(new Point(maxX,maxY));

        MovingPoint currentPoint = new MovingPoint(middleX, middleY,maxX,maxY);

        Set<Point> pointsDone = new HashSet<>();
        pointsDone.add(new Point(currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y));

        int directionIndex = 0;
        int length = 1;
        boolean lengthFlag = true;
        while(!edgesLeft.isEmpty()){
            for(int i=0; i<length;i++){
                switch(directionIndex){
                    case 0 : currentPoint.moveLeft(); break;
                    case 1 : currentPoint.moveUp(); break;
                    case 2 : currentPoint.moveRight(); break;
                    case 3 : currentPoint.moveDown(); break;
                }
                if(pointsDone.contains(currentPoint)){
                    continue;
                }
                pointsDone.add(new Point(currentPoint.x,currentPoint.y));
                consumer.accept(currentPoint);
                if(edgesLeft.contains(currentPoint)){
                    edgesLeft.remove(currentPoint);
                    if(edgesLeft.isEmpty()){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(++directionIndex > 3){
                directionIndex = 0;
            }
            if((lengthFlag = !lengthFlag)){
                length++;
            }
        }
    }
    static class MovingPoint extends Point{
        private int maxX;
        private int maxY;

        MovingPoint(int x, int y, int maxX, int maxY){
            super(x,y);
            this.maxX = maxX;
            this.maxY = maxY;
        }

        void moveUp(){
            if(this.y != 0){
                this.y--;
            }
        }

        void moveDown(){
            if(this.y != maxY){
                this.y++;
            }
        }

        void moveRight(){
            if(this.x != maxX){
                this.x++;
            }
        }

        void moveLeft(){
            if(this.x != 0){
                this.x--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

processing an image from your code would look somewhat similar to this:

```
here :{
            SpiralLoop.loop((Point p) -> {
            int color = image.getRGB(p.x, p.y);
            int red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int blue = color & 0x000000ff;
            if (red == 255) {
                System.out.println("Red has been found inside the picture");
                break here;
            }
        }), image.width, image.height);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is probably wayyy too slow, also I need to use it in 2 loops, and I am not sure how I would put this into them

Comment: Im not sure why you need two loops, i will edit answer to show implementation including processing image like in your question